# @OneToMany relationship with non primary key Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, entity-relationship, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have one **@Entity** called Team as

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="projects_participants")
    public class Team {

        @Id`enter code here`
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column
        private int id;



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name="participants_id")
    private int participants_id;

    public int getParticipants_id() {
        return participants_id;
    }

    public void setParticipants_id(int participants_id) {
        this.participants_id = participants_id;
    }









    /*
    @CollectionOfElements 
    private Set<Projects> projectsParticipant;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "team")
    public Set<Projects> getProjectsParticipant() {
        return projectsParticipant;
    }


    public void setProjectsParticipant(Set<Projects> projectsParticipant) {
        this.projectsParticipant = projectsParticipant;
    }
        */
}
```

I have another bean name **Projects** like

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "projects_participants", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "project_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "participants_id",referencedColumnName="participants_id")})
public Set<Team> getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public void setTeam(Set<Team> team) {
    this.team = team;
}
```

It works fine but the problem is project_participants Table has project_id and id of Team table. But I want project_id and Participants_id of Team table.
      **project_participants Table** is as below

[image]

**participants table as ***
[image]

Finally What I Want is table **project_participants** should have **project_project_id** and **participants_id** (not team_id).Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you're trying to model a m:n relationship, but not using the right annotation and principles.

1) Use `@ManyToMany` in combination with `@JoinTable` to model the m:n relationship like documented in the [jee5 api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html).

2) Don't model relationships to other objects via ID columns like you did with `participants_id`. With JPA you work with objects, not with their IDs, so your column would be a `Participant`.